# Change NSView background color when window has focus

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsview, nsoutlineview

I have noticed when an apps window contains an Outline view (such as XCode) it changes color when that window is in focus. With XCode for example, if the window is current then the outline view has a blueish background, if it looses focus it goes grey,

Can anyone help me to replicate this?  I presume its something to do with `drawRect:` but can only manage to get the color to change when the window loads.

Maybe its a built in function and I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do in your `-drawRect:` is check whether the window has **main** status and draw accordingly:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    if ([[self window] isMainWindow]) {
        // draw active appearance
    } else {
        // draw inactive appearance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A window's delegate gets messages whenever a window gets or resigns main or key window status. You can implement the appropriate methods (like `-windowDidBecomeMain:` and `-windowDidResignMain:`) in your window delegate to update the window and its subviews as necessary.

Comment: Changes in the key status (as opposed to main status) should trigger this behaviour.