# Repaint NSView when mainWindow changes

Tags: cocoa, swift2, appkit, redraw

I would like to change the background of an NSView depending on if the the window is focused.

I found this question: [Change NSView background color when window has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710134/change-nsview-background-color-when-window-has-focus)

And the first answer works fine except the redraw is not triggered when the windows loses or gains focus.

How can I trigger the redraw when the mainWindow changes?

Answer (score 2):

In your `NSWindow` delegate:

```
func windowDidBecomeMain(notification: NSNotification) {
    let theView = ...
    theView.needsDisplay = true
}

func windowDidResignMain(notification: NSNotification) {
    let theView = ...
    theView.needsDisplay = true
}
```

In your `NSView` subclass:

```
func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {
    if self.window.isMainWindow {
        // draw active appearance
    } else {
        // draw inactive appearance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNotificationCenter's `addObserver:selector:name:object:` or `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` to watch for `NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification` and `NSWindowDidResignMainNotification` with the view's `window` as the `object` argument.